# Integrating shapefile in spatialite DB with spatialite gui

Tags: shapefile, spatialite

For a project, i need a to display datas of a shapefile in an Android app (Geopaparazzi). I'm doing it by integrating the shapefile into a spatialite DB with spatialite gui **1.5** (1.6 having issues with Geopap).

It usually works fine, but with my new shapefiles in wgs 84, it gives me an error saying it can't open the shapefile.shx file, while it's in the directory with the .shp .

It still works with other files, so i don't really understand and i can't reach the person who created the new shapefiles right now.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to load the shapefiles into QGIS: If that fails too, the shx file is corrupt.

If it gets loaded (maybe without the shx file), you can save it in QGIS as a new shapefile.

Comment: I already tried to open it in QGIS, was working.
But didn't think of saving it, it seems to be working, huge thank you dude !